# How can I share my app made by Google App Maker with others?

Tags: google-app-maker

I created sample "Projects" app (Welcome Tutorial) using App Maker . I deployed the app and clicked on publish. How can I share it with my friends outside my domain ?

My domain is mahajiban.org , how someone with email id at gmail (outside my domain) can use it ? 
I am not able to download apk file also. How to find the apk file so that others can install it in my  mobile?
Thanks
Subhadip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Maker applications are restricted within the domain. Only users in the same domain can edit or access the applications.

The App Maker only creates web apps, no mobile apps, at this time. However, you can export your application and install it in another domain.

Answer (score -1):

You will also need to turn on AppMaker per organization or across the whole domain